# Positioning View Pager below Tablayout under Coordinatorlayout

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-coordinatorlayout

I have an Appbar, Tablayout and a ViewPager inside the CoordinatorLayout. But the ViewPager always overlapping every other views in the screen unless i specify a definite height other than 'MatchParent' or 'WrapContent'. i tried several things but nothing worked for me other than setting the height dynamically according to the screen size. I wonder! there must be some way to do this in the xml itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/logocolor"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"



        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            app:title="FlashBook"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/whitetish"

            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@color/logocolor"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/viewpager_layout"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/tablayout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"

    >

</include>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my activityLayout and..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/viewpagermain"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_appbartestactvity"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

this is the viewpager_layout..

Comment: add `app:layout_behavior=""` to include layout in `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: tried but no luck !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `ViewPager` directly as the `CoordinatorLayout` child:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   android:id="@+id/viewpagermain"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Or if you need the `<include` tag, add this line to the `<include` too:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Also, it's better to use `TabLayout` inside the `AppBarLayout` and under the `Toolbar`.

For being scrollable, add: `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`

To stick there after collapsing, add: `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"`

Comment: adding the layout_behavior to the <include> tag has no effect in my case. But i tested by adding the view pager directly without <include> along with the layout_behavior. It some how brings the viewPager below the appbar but not the tabLayout. I want it below the TabLayout..

Comment: Do you want the `TabLayout` stick there or being collapsible?  Add it under the `Toolbar` (as an `AppBarLayout` child) and give it `gravity: bottom` and then, to stick in there after collapsing, `add app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` and to being collapsbile, add: `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`.

Comment: Yes That's it. Adding the TabLayout inside the AppBarLayout solved the problem ..Thanks dude.!